# How to select a collection based on condition in EF Core?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I have an object that has two lists, and I need to select one of them based on a condition, like so:

```
    .Set<Person>()
    .Select(x => 
            Employees = x.IsManager ? x.WorkerList1 : x.WorkerList2
```

Both WorkerList1 and WorkerList2 are collections of the same type.

I tried unioning/concatinating the lists and it throws an error (cannot translate it).

I tried to select an intermediateQueryView object, like so:

```
    .Set<Person>()
    .Select(x => 
            Employees = x.IsManager 
                 ? x.WorkerList1.Select(x => new EmployeeView { //..assign properties here }) 
                 : x.WorkerList2.Select(x => new EmployeeView { //..assign properties here })
```

it also fails to translate.
Is there any way to achieve this?

I am using MSSQL provider.

Comment: I am maintaining a system in which I cannot change the db schema and I am trying to extract some data.

Comment: It's interesting to see the relevant part of the model and mappings - in particular how you have 2 collection navigation properties of the same type. Some sort of a join table? Anyway, if you need help with query, please provide the model so we can play with it. Also the EFC version, along with the db /provider type and version.

Comment: I have added the provider in the question (MSSQL), I cannot share with you my model, but this example should be enough to display the issue, is there any way to do this?

Comment: It might be enough to display it, but not to reproduce it. No one asks you for your real model, but we need something minimal ([mre]) to copy/paste and reproduce - you can't expect us to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought to split the queries?

```
var queryForManagers = queryable.Where(x => x.IsManager);
var queryForNotManagers = queryable.Where(x => !x.IsManager);

// now you can map and concat items independently...
```